# wxPython: Change the header's color

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I would like to know if there is a way to change the background colour of this part of the window in wxPython:

[image: window's header]

I already know how to change the title or the icon but I didn't find anything for the colour.

I use Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The short answer is NO**. WxPython uses the native graphic elements of the operating system as well as buttons, windows and others.

*On the other hand*, you can always create your own widgets.

In the following example I create my custom wxFrame and I remove the title bar that brings by default using the window styles. Then, by means of sizers, I simulate my own title bar, with its icon, text and buttons. The hard part is to make the window move by dragging it with the mouse but you have thousands of examples on the Internet.

I leave you an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

        self.SetSize((400, 299))

        # Creting the custom title bar
        self.panelTitleBar = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btnMinimize = wx.Button(self.panelTitleBar, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.BU_NOTEXT)
        self.btnMaximize = wx.Button(self.panelTitleBar, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.BU_NOTEXT)
        self.btnExit = wx.Button(self.panelTitleBar, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.BU_NOTEXT)
        self.panelBody = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnExitClick, self.btnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnMinimizeClick, self.btnMinimize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtnMaximizeClick, self.btnMaximize)
        self.panelTitleBar.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnTitleBarLeftDown)        
        self.panelTitleBar.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove) 


        self._isClickedDown = False;
        self._LastPosition = self.GetPosition();


        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()        

    def __set_properties(self):        
        self.SetTitle("frame")
        self.btnMinimize.SetMinSize((22, 22))
        self.btnMinimize.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("images\\btn_minimize.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
        self.btnMaximize.SetMinSize((22, 22))
        self.btnMaximize.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("images\\btn_maximize.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
        self.btnExit.SetMinSize((22, 22))
        self.btnExit.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("images\\btn_close.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
        self.panelTitleBar.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(44, 134, 179))
        self.panelBody.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))        

    def __do_layout(self):

        #Sizers:
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.FlexGridSizer(2, 1, 0, 0)
        sizerTitleBar = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 5, 0, 0)

        #Titlebar:
        iconTitleBar = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panelTitleBar, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap("[![enter image description here][1]][1]images\\tab03.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY))
        sizerTitleBar.Add(iconTitleBar, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)
        title = wx.StaticText(self.panelTitleBar, wx.ID_ANY, "My Window Title")
        title.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 255))
        title.SetFont(wx.Font(9, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD, 0, ""))
        sizerTitleBar.Add(title, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.BOTTOM | wx.TOP, 10)
        sizerTitleBar.Add(self.btnMinimize, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 2)
        sizerTitleBar.Add(self.btnMaximize, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 2)
        sizerTitleBar.Add(self.btnExit, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 2)
        sizerTitleBar.AddGrowableRow(0)
        sizerTitleBar.AddGrowableCol(1)

        self.panelTitleBar.SetSizer(sizerTitleBar)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.panelTitleBar, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.panelBody, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableRow(1)
        grid_sizer_1.AddGrowableCol(0)
        sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()

    def OnTitleBarLeftDown(self, event):            
        self._LastPosition = event.GetPosition()            

    def OnBtnExitClick(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnBtnMinimizeClick(self, event):
        self.Iconize( True )


    def OnBtnMaximizeClick(self, event):    
        self.Maximize(not self.IsMaximized())

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):        
        if event.Dragging():
            mouse_x, mouse_y = wx.GetMousePosition()                                
            self.Move(mouse_x-self._LastPosition[0],mouse_y-self._LastPosition[1])



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.frame.Center()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

This custom window can be moved, maximized, minimized and closed.

I hope this helps.

**P.S.**: *In order to execute the above code without errors, you will need to place these 4 images in a folder called "images" at the same level.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]